# Sql or operator

Tags: sql, operator-keyword

I have something I don't understand.
If my table is going like this:

```
name   age 
----   ----
din     18
mari    35
```

And i did this query:

```
select * from usernames
where age < 20 or name not like 'din'
```

And all the table and rows printed, my goal is to print who was not called 'din' and under the age of 20.

Can someone tell me where is my mistake?

i asked here another q .. sorry about it.

Comment: Change your OR to an AND.

Comment: @Alicia I don't search for an answers , i search for explanation. 
If or executed when one False and one True - 
it will not print ages under 20 but will print all the names who not called din , right ? or i wrong?

Comment: But you already say "who was not called 'din' and under the age of 20" in the question, with "and". So... @Alicia probably assumed that the OR was a simple error.

Comment: @MrLister I'm sorry. but i still don't get it. why is not working ?

Comment: Perhaps you are being confused by the `not` of the 2nd clause. Does it make more sense if written like: `where age < 20 or name like 'mari'`?

Comment: `Moreover, does someone know how to insert multiple values into table in one single query?` - One question at a time please (unless they are closely related).

Comment: @Turophile 
According to my logic, if we go according to your command
It prints Mary.
my wrong , it will print also din because he is under 18

Comment: The expression is true for the first record, because age<20. The expression is also true for the second record, because name is not 'din'. Not sure how else to explain. Again, you said what you wanted was "**who was not called 'din' and under the age of 20**", so yes, that's what you should have put in the sql. AND, not OR.

Answer (score 4):

Explanation:

```
where age < 20 or name not like 'din'
```

breaks down to:

```
where <something> or <something else>
```

For each row, < something > and < something else > will be evaluated. The `or` means the result will be true if either is true. Only one of them needs to be true for the row to be selected.

In your example, the first row meets the `age < 20` condition. The rest of the test is not important (and it evaluates as false) because we already have a true. The second row evaluates as false for `age < 20` but true for `name not like 'din'` so as explained above, if either side of the OR is true, the result is true, and thus row 2 is returned in the results.

That is why both rows are returned.

Add this data to your table to help illustrate:

```
name   age 
----   ----
din     28  (both sides false)
mari    15  (both sides true)
```